# If directory contains exe or msi file, start it with command line arguments

Tags: qt, file, command, switch-statement, exe

This app is intended for use on Windows only. It is to be built in QT Creator. I'm using `7zip.exe` as an example as it is very quick and easy to test with.
I have a list of directories, each one contains a single `*.exe` or `*.msi` file.
On `pushbutton_clicked()` within `Qt` I want to go to the single directory that I specify and start whichever executable or `*.msi` file is in that directory. The `*.exe` or `*.msi` filename will change from time to time otherwise I could simple use the system command.

> system ("start 7zip\7zip.exe /S");

My trouble has been the fact that I want to run a wildcard e.g. `*.exe` or `*.msi` and add a command line switch to it.

I now want to execute the single file in path and add the argument `/S`

I had this working in a batch file:

```
for /F %%a in ('dir /b 7zip\*.exe') do SET app1=%%~na

%app1% /S
```

but am unsure how to implement it in `Qt`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use 2 things: [QDirIterator](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdiriterator.html) to iterate directories in the system and [QProcess](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qprocess.html) to launch the external process with arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks AlexanderVX

They were just what was needed. I'm sure there are many ways to make this more elegant but it does exactly what i want it to do now.

```
    void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    //set initial directory to search for the exe file
    QDirIterator file("7zip", QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
    while (file.hasNext())
    {
        file.next();
        QString prog = file.fileName(); //get actual filename
        QStringList cswitch;
        cswitch << "/S";  //create the command switch to use when running the exe
        QProcess *install = new QProcess(this);  // create new process called install
        QDir::setCurrent("7zip"); //set working directory needed to install the exe
        install->start(prog, cswitch); //launch the exe with the desired command switch
    }
}
```